# How to pass bulk value to reset in JExcel cell

Tags: jexcelapi

I am using JExcel in my project below code I need each time  call script to set new value in JExcel cell.
I need to know how to pass a set of array value to pass bulk data.

```
$('#id').jexcel('setValue', 'A1', 9999, true);

$('#id').jexcel('setValue', 'A8', 123, true);

$('#id').jexcel('setValue', 'C3', 3242, true);

$('#id').jexcel('setValue', 'D1', 'Test', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

it has an API setData in the version 3, which gives users an easy way to pass an array.

for example, you have defined your jexcel already, and now you want to set the data in bulk with an array

```
$('#my-spreadsheet').jexcel('setData', array_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the version 3 you can apply setRowData to change one row.